# About the array in bash shell script

Tags: arrays, shell

Just a simple question.

I have an array:

```
array=("1 2 3" "4 5 6")
```

If I do:

```
echo ${array[0]}
echo ${array[1]}
```

1 2 3 or 4 5 6 will be shown.

However, if I do:

```
for iter in ${array[@]}
do
echo $iter
done
```

The shown value is not as I expected.... Can anyone give me the right way to use it?

Comment: What do you expect? I get "1 2 3" and "4 5 6", the values in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quotation** is what you need:

```
for iter in "${array[@]}"; do 
  echo "$iter"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @chepner. Quoting the `iter` variable is not really needed, isn't it?

Comment: It depends. Unquoted, the value of `$iter` will undergo word-spliting before each word is passed as a separate argument to `echo`. Quoted, the entire string is passed as a single argument. Compare with something like `iter="a    b"` (there are supposed to be multiple spaces between `a` and `b`).

Comment: @chepner Aah I can see the difference using `for iter in "${array[@]}"; do printf "%s\n" $iter; done` and `for iter in "${array[@]}"; do printf "%s\n" "$iter"; done` and yea that multiple spaces example is good to understand the reason too. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @HaoShen, the real magic here is quoting `"${array[@]}"` -- See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays and look for the paragraph containing "when the word appears within double quotes"